# preview title doesn't show on Facebook post

Tags: html, facebook

I add OG tags to my html pages:

for some reason, when i paste url on Facebook I don't see the title tag content in the preview post.

Why is that?

Here is example for url -

http://www.followmyroutes.com/index.php?page=itinPage&itinID=16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refreshed the tags in the debugger for you: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

Now they should show up correctly.

Comment: Thanks. do i need to do that for each and every url/page i have on my website?

Comment: if the og tags change, yes. or just wait if facebook re-scrapes it, not sure if they do that for existing og tags, or how often that happens. og tags are not meant to be changed.